# How to align the textview to right in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am displaying the **date and the cricket score in a table**. But my problem is when I am displaying the No **1,2,3,....upto 9 it is working fine...But when I displayed 10 the date in the next date column is moving one place right because of two digit number 10.** How to solve this issue?

[image]

Any help will be thankful....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alignment can be done with `android:gravity="right"`

Another option could be, to check if your number is smaller than 10 and prepend a zero figure

Comment: use android:weight attribute to every widget.