# Alignment problems with textview in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am building an app that is in 3 languages. The problem is that the text in textview is not aligning well. See image below -
[image: Alignment Issues]

I have set the gravity to start on all textviews.
I have tried [Textview issue with text align](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23469896/textview-issue-with-text-align), [Android: Text in TextView not aligned well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23235353/android-text-in-textview-not-aligned-well), [How to align the textview to right in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10332153/how-to-align-the-textview-to-right-in-android)
The xml is as follows -

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F2D77C"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".AdActivity" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#F2D77C"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#F2D77C"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:weightSum="2" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/topCity"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#F2D77C"
                    android:paddingBottom="7dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/topPrice"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="top|right|end"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#F2D77C"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
<!-- 
            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
 -->
<!--             </HorizontalScrollView>  -->

            <ImageSwitcher
                android:id="@+id/imageSwitcher1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:minHeight="400dp" >

            </ImageSwitcher>

                <Gallery
                    android:id="@+id/gallery1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:spacing="5dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewPrice"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#F2D77C"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#262626" >

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="gone" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Ad Code"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/adCode"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Test code"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Viewed"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="20dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/views"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:weightSum="4" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView5"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:minWidth="50dp"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="@string/city"
                        android:textColor="#5B554E"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/city"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="3"
                        android:gravity="start"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:textAlignment="gravity"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:weightSum="4" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView7"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="@string/date"
                        android:textColor="#5B554E"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/date"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="3"
                        android:gravity="start"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:textAlignment="gravity"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:weightSum="4" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="@string/price"
                        android:textColor="#5B554E"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/price"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="3"
                        android:gravity="start"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:textAlignment="gravity"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                </TableRow>

            </TableLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#20202020"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="@string/description"
                android:textColor="#6B5F53"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/description"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#F2E0A7"
                android:minHeight="75dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#20202020"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="@string/publisher_details"
                android:textColor="#6B5F53"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp" >

                <TableRow
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView11"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="@string/name"
                        android:textColor="#6B5F53"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/name"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="TextView"
                        android:textColor="#999999" />

                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonCallCar"
                style="@drawable/button_wh"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_bl"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:text="Call" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonAltCall"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_bl"
                android:text="Call" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonFacebook"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_bl"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/facebook"
                android:text="@string/share" />

</LinearLayout>



    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is occurring in Kurdish and Arabic but not in English(see image for English).
[image: English]

Comment: Setting gravity to start for all the textviews is not going to look good for arabic text as they start from right to left

Comment: Left aligning places the text on the extreme left which will not look right on larger screens, especially on tablets, as it will put too much space between the elements. And the other point is that the alignment is inconsistent with gravity=start.